# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(k)+1}$ where $f(k+1)=f(k)^2+f(k), f(1)=\frac{1}{29}$ converges to 29

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I got this question in a three hour test in a korean math class with the sum ending at 2015.
After the test, I tried calculating it on a computer where the result was a bit greater than 29

I tried using a generating function to calculate the limit but the recursion made it hard to express the function out of itself.

Is there a simple way to calculate the limit?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: So your conjecture is that more generally, the series converges to $\frac1{f(1)}$?

Comment: It seems to me that it does converge to $\frac{1}{f(1)}$

Comment: In fact, this series is the result of applying the greedy algorithm in computing the [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) of $\dfrac{1}{f(1)}$ based on $\{\dfrac{1}{f(1)+k}|k \in \Bbb{Z}^+ \}$, and since the sum of numbers in the latter set diverges, the fraction will always be successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(1)>0$, the sequence $f(k)$ is strictly increasing. As also the difference sequence $f(k)^2$ is strictly increasing, we conclude that $f(k)\to \infty$.
Once we have $f(k)>1$, we have
$$f(k+1)=f(k)(1+f(k))>2f(k)$$
So by induction $f(k+m)>2^mf(k)$.
This gives us the bound
$$\tag1 \begin{align}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{f(k+m)+1}&\le \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{f(k+m)}\\&\le \sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac1{2^mf(k)}=\frac2{f(k)}\qquad\text{if }f(k)>1\end{align}$$
for the series tail.
In particular, our series converges for every positive $f(1)$.

Let $F(x)$ be the value of the series if $f(1)=x$, $x>0$.
From $(1)$, we get
$$\tag2 0<F(x)<\frac2{x}\qquad\text{if }x>1.$$
In particular
$$ \lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=0.$$
By chopping off the first summand, we find
$$F(f(1)) = \frac1{f(1)+1}+F(f(2))$$
Let $G(x)=F(x)-\frac1x$. Then this becomes
$$\begin{align}G(f(1))+\frac1{f(1)} &= \frac1{f(1)+1}+G(f(2))+\frac1{f(2)}\\&=\frac1{f(1)+1}+G(f(2))+\frac1{f(1)^2+f(1)}\end{align}$$
which simplifies to
$$ G(f(1))=G(f(2)).$$
By induction,
$$\tag3 G(f(1))=G(f(n))$$
for all $n$.
As also
$$ \lim_{x\to+\infty}G(x)=0$$
and we already know $f(n)\to +\infty$, we thus conclude from $(3)$ that $G(f(1))=0$.
In other words,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{f(k)+1}=\frac1{f(1)}$$
if $f(1)>0$.

Comment: Reminder: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|136.1126).  It didn't just apply last year.  It still applies, @Hagen.